# How to print each result of Oracle Queries in separate sheets in Python?

Tags: database, python-3.x, spreadsheet, xlrd

Let's suppose I have a list with multiple queries such as:

```
queries = ['select * from emp', 'select * from dept', 'select * from country']
```

Now I want to print the result of each query in a separate sheet with Python.
How do I do that? In addition, if I have names of tables in a separate list in Python, e.g.

```
tables = ['emp', 'dept', 'country']
```

Can I make these table names their sheet names in their respective table results?
That means that if I am storing information of 'select * from emp' table in a separate sheet, then its sheet name should be 'Emp'.